# opencv merge two cropped images

Tags: python, image, opencv, conv-neural-network

Hi I'm new to Image Processing and Mask R-CNN. I already cropped 2 detected crack segments from the image thru Mask R-CNN, however they appear to be separate image per mask. Now, I want to combine the two cropped segments into one image. But my problem is, there are white parts (encircled area) that appear within the cracks. I'm missing some parts of the crack. It seems some pixels are converted to white, I don't understand. How to solve this?

Masked crack:
[image: Masked crack]

Cropped crack:
[image: cropped]

Problematic output:
[image]

```
display_instances(image, r['rois'], r['masks'], r['class_ids'],
                  class_names, r['scores'])

mask = r['masks']
mask = mask.astype(int)
mask.shape

for i in range(mask.shape[2]):
temp = skimage.io.imread(ROOT_DIR + "/" + "crack2.jpg")
for j in range((temp).shape[2]):
    temp[:,:,j] = temp[:,:,j] * mask[:,:,i]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
plt.imshow(temp)

if (i==0):
    tem_p = temp
else:
    tem_p = cv2.add(tem_p, temp)
    plt.imshow(tem_p)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the problem is that the two contours have overlapping areas (which are the white pieces). When merging you add the values of the two areas, thus it results in a pixel value of +-255, which is white in a binary image. Maybe try pasting one image on the other without adding the pixel values

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much, you have enlightened me. However, I tried the tem_p = temp.paste(tem_p), it says error for numpy. I googled codes for pasting images using numpy, I can't seem to make it work :(

Comment: Hello, maybe you could add rotation steps to your algorithm, then you'll be able to sum rotated detections and filter final results with a threshold so you'll be able to have a confidence-like threshold for your detected cracks.

Comment: Hi, @lamourettejean-baptiste thank you very much. But I'm afraid I have little knowledge what you suggest. I don't understand how am I going to implement it. Sorry I'm new and I'm a student

Comment: You could also try pasting one contour, then setting the overlapping bit to 0, then add the second contour. This way you don't double the value of the overlapping bits

Comment: Hi, @Epsi thank you so much. I solved it by taking hint from the overlapping bits. I used cv2.bitwise_or(tem_p, temp). Surprisingly it worked!

Comment: No problem, I am glad to hear you solved your problem!